# JQuery, AJAX, comparing returned JSON value

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

What am I doing wrong here? The grey class is removed for the first conditional (===5) but is not removed with the other conditional statements?

Thanks for looking at it,

**Javascript:**

```js
 function getTrophy() {
  $.ajax({
   url: "ajax/ajax_dashboard.php?f=14",
   type: "GET",
   success: function(data) {
    var json;
    json = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(parseInt(json.volunteer[0])===5) {
     $("#volunteer-trophy").removeClass("grey");
    }    
    if(parseInt(json.mindful[0])>=5) {
     $("#mindful-trophy1").removeClass("grey");
    }    
    if(parseInt(json.mindful[0])>=10) {
     $("#mindful-trophy2").removeClass("grey");
    }
    if(parseInt(json.mindful[0])>=15) {
     $("#mindful-trophy3").removeClass("grey");
    }
    if(parseInt(json.mindful[0])>=20) {
     $("#mindful-trophy4").removeClass("grey");
    }
      }
    })
  }
```

**JSON**

```
​{"volunteer" : "5", "mindful" : "10"}
```

Comment: Why are you appending a `[0]` at the end of each property? `json.mindful[0]` is the string `"1"`. Next time, use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and try to debug this yourself: use `console.log(json)`, `console.log(json.mindful)` and `console.log(json.mindful[0])` if you need to.

Comment: `json.volunteer[0]` is the first character in the string "5" which is 5, so you got lucky that time.

Comment: 1 is not greater than or equal to 5. it is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the intended result, so your code should be like this:

```
            if(parseInt(json.volunteer)===5) {
                $("#volunteer-trophy").removeClass("grey");
            }               
            if(parseInt(json.mindful)>=5) {
                $("#mindful-trophy1").removeClass("grey");
            }
```

Better still, to avoid errors, you should store the `volunteer` and `mindful` in variables:

```
            var volunteer = parseInt(json.volunteer);
            var mindful   = parseInt(json.mindful);
            if( volunteer === 5) {
                $("#volunteer-trophy").removeClass("grey");
            }               
            if( mindful >= 5) {
                $("#mindful-trophy1").removeClass("grey");
            }
```

UPDATE: As pointed out by @charlietfl, the last 3 conditions are redundant, since the test for `mindful > 5` fulfills the condition for the three conditions after it.

Comment: `[0]` could be perfectly valid with any JSON structure or any array. The reason, this isn’t working is because `[0]` was used on a string.

Comment: so, misleading description, but correct... *ish* code. With your setup the first condition would fail because `5 !== "5"`. but... that would have been true for the OP's code as well.... so who knows.

Comment: @Xufox, yes you are right, however, in this instance the OP's use of it is not what he intended, as is evident from his confusion as to why the code is not working.

Comment: see, the thing is, it being a string, would have made the first condition fail in the OP's code, but they said it worked, which doesn't make any sense...

Comment: @KevinB, it worked because it's wrapped in the parseInt() call, which effectively converted it to an integer, so it worked with the strict equality `===` operator

Comment: last 3 `if()` are redundant and will already be covered by 2nd `if()`

Comment: Ah, i completely missed the parseInt

Comment: @charlietfl, yes, you are right, since it's basically removing the "grey" class in every case > 5.